# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 calabash

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods, calabash-ios

I'm trying to set up calabash in my project.

I follow this tutorial: http://angelolloqui.com/blog/25-Acceptance-testing-with-Calabash-and-CocoaPods

But it's like now the new target doesn't find the rest of clases in pods and I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in INCWorldWeatherOnline.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in INCWorldWeatherOnline.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTLJSONAdapter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in INCWorldWeatherOnline.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTLModel", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_INCForecastCondition in INCForecastCondition.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_INCCurrentCondition in INCCurrentCondition.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MTLValueTransformer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in INCForecastCondition.o
      objc-class-ref in INCCurrentCondition.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTLModel", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_INCForecastCondition in INCForecastCondition.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_INCCurrentCondition in INCCurrentCondition.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The original target is working without problems

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i made Build Active Architecture Only  "NO"
and just uploaded the build on itunes store using product -> archive
i dont know why this happened but it work for me

Answer (score -2):

In your target's Build Settings, try to change `Build Active Architecture Only`:

```
Debug->Yes
```

Comment: I am down voting this because building for the active architecture will lead to incompatible architecture problems during Calabash testing.